# Spring non singleton controller

Tags: spring

I am building a spring based application that handles server-side game management for a mobile game app. The stack is Spring/Hibernate/Jersey. I want the clients (mobile) to call a REST API to update/retrieve the game state.

I created a `TournamentController` class which responsability is to update the tournament state using some business logic. This class is designed to be instanciated every time an operation on a Tournament is required and then thrown away.

```
public class TournamentController {

    @Autowired
    private TournamentDAO tournamentDAO;

    private final Tournament tournament;

    public TournamentController( Tournament tournament ) {
        this.tournament = tournament;
    }

    public void startTournament() {
        if ( tournament.getState() != TournamentState.SETUP ) {
            throw new TournamentAlreadyStartedException();
        }

        tournament.setState( TournamentState.IN_PROGRESS );

        //... some other logic and calls to other DAOs

        tournamentDAO.save( tournament );
    }

}
```

I also created a `TournamentResource` class that is the REST front end for the tournament. It's responsability is to do some basic validation (user security, ...) and exception translation.

```
@Path( "/tournament" )
@Component
@Scope( "prototype" )
public class TournamentResource {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog( TournamentResource.class );

    @Autowired
    private TournamentDAO tournamentDAO;

    @GET
    @Path( "{tournamentId}/start" )
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Transactional
    public TournamentDTO startTournament( @PathParam( "tournamentId" ) long tournamentId ) {
        Tournament tournament = tournamentDAO.getTournament( tournamentId, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE );
        if ( tournament == null ) {
            throw new WebApplicationException( Status.NOT_FOUND );
        }

        try {
            TournamentController controller = new TournamentController( tournament );
            controller.startTournament();

        } catch ( TournamentAlreadyStartedException e ) {
            log.warn( "Could not start tournament " + tournamentId + " since it is already started." );
            throw new RestException( Status.BAD_REQUEST, "Tournament already started" );
        }

        return DTOConverterUtil.getTournament( tournament );
    }

}
```

I am using load time weaving with AspectJ. Here is my context:

```
   <context:annotation-config />

   <!-- Make spring aware ANY pojo with the @Configurable annotation -->
   <context:spring-configured />

   <!-- Scan all classes in com.mdarveau for annotations -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="so.question" />

   <!-- Load Time Weaver -->
   <context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" aspectj-weaving="on" />

   <!-- DB config -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      ...
   </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mdarveau.fnp.model" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
         </value>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>

   <!-- enable @Transactional -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" mode="aspectj" />
```

My `TournamentResource` class is a singleton by design and is working well.

My problem is that when it instanciate the `TournamentController` using `new` instead of spring, it's `@Autowired` attributes does not seems to be wired correctly. I tried to add the `@Component` annotation on it without success.

Should I make `TournamentResource` `ApplicationContextAware` and create the `TournamentController` through spring?

This must be a fairly common problem. I see a lot of examples where the backend is a singleton but I would like to avoid passing the `Tournament` to every method call on `TournamentController` (all then to all private methods in `TournamentController`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have load-time weaving and `<context:spring-configured />`, you can declare your `TournamentController` as `@Configurable`.

It will enable autowiring for instances of `TournamentController` created with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Right, anything that you create with `new` is not under the Spring bean factory's control.  Calling `new` means you are on your own.

I'm not sure why your `TournamentController` needs a private reference to a `Tournament`.  You make a point of saying this is a REST front end.  If I understand it correctly, REST is based on HTTP, which is a stateless protocol.

I'm not sure where you think the `Tournament` instance will come from.  If Spring instantiates that `TournamentController`, then you should wire in a reference to the Tournament in question in either an annotation or XML configuration.

I'd recommend that you make it a Spring resource that's wired in or rethink your design to eliminate it from the Controller.

Comment: The "TournamentController" is basically just a manager on a specific "Tournament" so it is instanciated anytime something has to be done on a tournament (there will be multiple tournaments going on at any given time). I would like it to have a private reference to the "Tournament" so I don't have to pass references to "Tournament" to every public and private methods. A little bit like a mediator pattern.

Comment: So it's not stateless.  You need to provide a REST method for users to be able to specify which Tournament they want, which will be an annotated method in the controller.  It need not have a reference inside it.  You should like you don't understand REST or mediators.

Comment: Yep, this is the "@PathParam( "tournamentId" )" parameter to my rest method :-). The method get's the tournament Id, retrieve it from persistence and then instanciate the TournamentController (passing the Tournament) reference so it can act on it in the scope of the request.

Comment: You should be thinking about keeping the tournament in session or cache, not a controller instance.  Your current design requires every user to get their own controller, and the controller to know its users.  That's not RESTful.

Comment: I could but I want to keep the app session less. The TournamentController is just a little wrapper (mediator) around the Tournament so I can interact with it.

Comment: You have an accepted answer.  Go see if it works.  I don't believe it will.  Come back if it's a problem.

Comment: I confirm, it works. My REST layer load the Tournament based in the received id, I create a new TournamentController (could be called mediator) which is handled by spring because of the @Configurable and the required DAO are injected (@Autowired). The Tournament which was modifed by the TournamentController is then persisted and the REST call return. Thanks for your help!